# How to use VFP4 instructions in iOS?

Tags: ios

I want to use VFMA instruction in my project. However, the assembler will report an error because ARMv7 assembler does not support VFP4 instruction set. When I remove ARMv7 architecture, the app cannot be uploaded to App Store.

How should I handle this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have already had a solution according to my effort. And CPU Dasher 2.1 is available on App Store.